# Object variables missing in cascaded Promise

Tags: node.js, promise

So I have looked high and low for an answer to this, so apologies if my Google Foo is bad...

I have a Node.JS module that has Promise functions that sometime call other Promise functions (this is example code, but it behaves the same way as the code I'm actually trying to write):

```
"use strict";

function Top() {
  this.var1 = "";
  this.var2 = [];
  this.debug = 0;
}

Top.prototype.longRun1 = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    // call out to network service here...
    this.var1 = "LR1";
    this.var2.push(this.var1);
    Top.prototype.longRun2().then((out) => {
      resolve(out);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("LR2:" + err);
    });
  });
}

// longRun2() can be called by other non-Promise functions.
Top.prototype.longRun2 = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    // call to a second network service...
    this.var1 = "LR2";
    this.var2.push(this.var1);
    resolve(this.var2.length);
  })
}

Top.prototype.dump = function() {
  return this.var2;
}

module.exports = Top;
```

And used like so:

```
var Top = require('./test2.js');

var t = new Top();

t.longRun1().then((out) => {
  console.log(out);
  console.log(t.var1);
  console.log(t.dump());
  console.log(t.var2.length);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("TOP:" + err);
});
```

When I run this, I get this error:  `LR2:TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

So all of the Object's `this.` variables seem to be gone in the second Promise :(  I thought that since both functions belong to the Object, they would inherit the Object's `this.` variables, but seems that my thinking was incorrect.

Is there some kind of scoping that I need to add in order to reference the Object variables in the second Promise function??

longRun2() function requires the result of longRun1(), so order is important.  Once longRun1() has been called, longRun2() and other functions can be called directly.

Thanks for you help and insights!

Comment: Avoid `new Promise` if you can. It's usually the wrong thing and completely unneeded. It will cause your code to do surprising/unintended things.

Comment: @Evert   So how to I restructure the code??  If I change the calls to ``return Promise((resolve,reject) => {}``  I get errors:  ``TypeError: undefined is not a promise``

Comment: Here's an example of how I would rewrite longRun1: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/CoewDgdGBOIC7wJ5gKYQDYgHYHMBKArlgIwAEAvKQGZEDGcAltqQBQCUpA3gFCmm+k4ACwYBnCADcAhtDKUARABk8xeQG4BwsZJkAmKAVFCWW8dNlsNfaCjgFoWUqEgx4SVBmz4iu9gL4QtFJwtMYsKNDQHOQAfFz+fLTYoiDoaJg4LEp4ugBc8qQA1KQRUVakAL6W3BVAA

Comment: Note that the .catch clause is also a red flag for me, as it causes longRun1 to return with `undefined` even if there was an error. If you *must* log errors, and there in that function, you should probably re-throw the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you call the method using `prototype`. In that case `Top.prototype` is binded to `this`. In general `this` is an object "before a dot". That's why in the first call `t.longRun1()`, `this` is `t`.

Correct call would be:

```
this.longRun2().then((out) => {
  resolve(out);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("LR2:" + err);
});
```

If you want to have more control on `this` variable you can use one of these:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Ah!  Ok....so at least I was on the right track with it being a scoping issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One more thing for those who may stumble upon this:

szatkus's answer worked for me.....just not at first, and it was a weird one (well, to me it was.....)

I changed my test code above, and it worked correctly, so I went to the code that I'm working on, and it still crapped out, even with the fix?!?  After looking long and hard at the differences between the test code, and my real code, I found one difference:

In my code:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
```

The test code:

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
```

Functionally (as far as I knew) they are the same...the test code just uses a more recent convention than what I was taught many moons ago.  I change my real code to the newer way of calling functions, and (Taa-Daah) it worked!

Maybe someone can comment about why the different results for the two different forms of calling a function?